# Error with camera calibration file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I got this error when running

```
 roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

[image: image description]

what is the solution for this error !
thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49116/error-with-camera-calibration-file/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi salma,

Don't worry about it, the kinect still works with this error message. It is caused (I believe after working more than 2 month with the kinect) that it is due to the depth registration. But you have nothing to worry about, everything works fine evenif you have this error message.

By the way, when you post a message, you should always specify :

- what version of ROS you are using
- what Ubuntu you are running it on

Bests regards,

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using multiple Kinects? Were you restarting the openni nodes? It seems to me that either you have other nodes running with conflicting namespaces or you have run nodes previously that were not appropriately closed.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1